# Is it safe to leave a random exposed yellow wire in hard-wired smoke detector?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Went to change a battery in a hard-wired smoke detector- bought the house about 2 years ago so we didn't install this.  Found a random exposed yellow wire with no cap on it.  Feels kind of funny if we just stick it back up in the ceiling!
Is it safe?  There's 2 white, 1 black, 2 orange and this single yellow wire.
There's one white, one black and one yellow in this tiny little hanging plastic square, but the yellow one is just exposed.
Would love to upload a picture.
Please help.  We've been living in the house for 2 years like this.
Thanks,
Nancy

Comment: The Yellow could be the signal wire to the home central fire alarm. Do you have one ? If not just ignore it and cap it

Comment: Any non connected wire should be capped at least.  The main problem is what that wire is for.  Is it for an extra option or needed.

Comment: What gauge is the wire?  Are the wires coming from conduit or NM jacket?  If NM jacket then what color?  Low voltage wire for HVAC and such has a tendency to come in a brown cable jacket and gauge of 18AWG or smaller.  High voltage indoor wire often has white, black, yellow, or orange jacket, 14AWG or larger.  Outdoor wire ends to have gray jacket.  High voltage wire can safely be used for low voltage, and this does appear to be common, but high voltage on low voltage wire is not safe, but also seen more commonly than it should in spite of the safety implications.

Comment: @MacGuffin thank you for sharing, seldom to newer HVAC wires run at Fire Alarms

Comment: @Ruskes  Low voltage smoke detectors may be rare, at least in American homes, but they do exist and appear would meet building code if used.  Also, the wire seen may be unrelated to the smoke detector, it may be a leftover from a prior repair or remodel.  Maybe there was a HVAC device of some kind there before (remote thermometer perhaps) and someone put in central HVAC and reused the spot for a smoke detector.

Comment: @MacGuffin -- yeah, the usual time you see low voltage smokes is when someone has a burglar alarm system installed

Comment: @MacGuffin Remote HVAC thermometer in the ceiling ?

Comment: You can upload a picture by editing the question and then clicking on the picture icon.

Comment: "Remote HVAC thermometer in the ceiling ?"  First possibility is people do stupid things.  Second, it doesn't have to be a thermometer but something else HVAC related, including an old A/C control wire going by the hole but was damaged and left dangling during the install of the smoke detector.  Third, people use "thermometer wire" for things other than HVAC, such as smoke detectors, burglar alarms, intercoms, in-wall speakers, and more.  The point is to identify the kind of wire or cable this is to better decipher it's function and therefore if it poses any threat.

Comment: I'm glad you "would love to upload a picture", please do so! [Edit] your question, click the "sun & mountain" icon and link to the pic, or, just put the cursor at the bottom of the text box & drag a picture from your computer onto the text edit box - either way, the system will take care of uploading & hosting the image for you. Without the picture, though, it's going to be _very_ difficult for us to help you out...